# Calculate file transfer speed to pendrive

Tags: c#, copy, file-transfer

I want to copy files to a pendrive or to a hard drive with c#. When I copy them, I can check the transfer speed by checking the time and how many kilobytes I have already copied. But is there a way to quickly guess the speed before starting the copying? I want to know how much time the copying will take.
Is there a way for this?

Thank you.

Comment: Look at the Windows File Copy dialog and how well they solved that same problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But is there a way to quickly guess the speed before starting the copying?

I donot think so.

If there would have been a way, Windows Copy-Paste time duration (remaining time) prediction would be much better.

Currently i think, For any copy paste operation
  Windows find out length of all data to be copied. 
  Then during copy operation, it find out how much is copied, and how much is left. Based on it, it guesses the remaining time. 
  During entire copy-paste process, the remaining time is recalculated again and again.

Example,
 Suppose data to be copied is 100 MB.
 If after 1 min, 1 MB is copied, remaining time would come as 99min.
 If after 2 min, 4 MB is copied, remaining time would come as 48min.
 If after 10 min, 5MB is copied, remaining time would come as 190 min.

Note -> Above is my observation, and not a authoritative answer based on internal algorithm implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Distance = Rate * Time

Take the Distance (remaining kilobites) an divide by the Rate (Kilobites per second). You should be able to get a rough time in seconds.

Comment: Rate not only depends upon the supported speed of device, but also on file type. A 700MB video file will be copied much faster than A 100 MB HTML docs folder.

Comment: And is there a way to somehow measure that? I mean for excample does Windows know that the video file will be copied faster?

Comment: It is file size and number of files that matters (not file type, i have used as illustrations only). One 10MB file will take much lesser time then 10000 1kB files. Reason -> File format. While traversing file data, all information is present in some manner (linked list/bock index etc). When multiple files are involved, it adds additional overhead of reading 10000 file headers and files that are stored in spordaic manner.

Comment: I don't disagree, however we are talking about time to scan vs time to transfer. The total bytes transferred include the headers will be the same for 1000 1 byte files as 1 1000 byte file (if you assume meta data is included). Once you accumulate the total size the only additional overhead is File Open, File Close, some filesystem cleanup and perhaps verification. It just depends on what you are interested in.